# TFS Build server and Nuget

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, nuget, nuget-package

Hello i have a project that uses nuget libraries, and build always fails with error:

```
Debug | Any CPU
5 error(s), 4 warning(s)
$/TEST/TEST/TEST.sln - 5 error(s), 4 warning(s),View Log File
D:\Builds\3\TEST\CI - Check In Build\src\TEST\.nuget\NuGet.targets (92): Unable to find version '1.3.1' of package 'Callisto'.
D:\Builds\3\TEST\CI - Check In Build\src\TEST\.nuget\NuGet.targets (92): Unable to find version '5.0.8' of package 'Newtonsoft.Json'.
D:\Builds\3\TEST\CI - Check In Build\src\TEST\.nuget\NuGet.targets (92): Unable to find version '1.5.4.3' of package 'winrtxamltoolkit'.
D:\Builds\3\TEST\CI - Check In Build\src\TEST\.nuget\NuGet.targets (92): Unable to find version '1.5.4.3' of package 'WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.DataVisualization'.
D:\Builds\3\TEST\CI - Check In Build\src\TEST\.nuget\NuGet.targets (92): The command ""D:\Builds\3\TEST\CI - Check In Build\src\TEST\.nuget\NuGet.exe" install "D:\Builds\3\TEST\CI - Check In Build\src\TEST\TEST\packages.config" -source "" -NonInteractive -RequireConsent -solutionDir "D:\Builds\3\TEST\CI - Check In Build\src\TEST\ "" exited with code 1.
EXEC: The remote name could not be resolved: 'www.nuget.org'
EXEC: The remote name could not be resolved: 'www.nuget.org'
EXEC: The remote name could not be resolved: 'www.nuget.org'
EXEC: The remote name could not be resolved: 'www.nuget.org'
$/TEST/TEST/SAPSalesCentral.sln compiled
```

Package restore is enabled.

I have a packages folder on my developers machine - where all my nuget packages are stored.

Can i manually add packages folder to my project and include .DLL from it to store it on build server so that nuget restore wasn't needed?

Comment: Can you ping nuget.org from the build server?

Comment: Check my additional question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your build server doesn't have internet access, you need to setup a [**local NuGet feed**](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds). You can use the build server itself for that purpose.

Comment: and this should be done on Build Server machine itself or any other machine that build server has access to?

Comment: Any machine with Visual Studio will do. I've done it on my dev workstation and deployed the local NuGet on the build server. The only caveat is downloading all the packages (.nupkg files) from an internet accessible machine and then copying them to the build server.

Answer (score 1):

Can the user running the Build service access internet? Sometimes you have to logon using that account a set a proxy in Internet Explorer.

Comment: Check my additional question. In other words, yes, Build service can't access internet due security purpose any other options